# Java split text into sentences based on "...", “.”, "?", "!",

Tags: java

How can I split a text into an array of sentences using regex?

Example Text:

```
This is test... Sentense number 2. Sentence number 3?
```

Expected output:

```
This is test... 

Sentense number 2.  

Sentence number 3?
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [a BreakIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html):

```
  String s = "This is test... Sentense number 2. Sentence number 3?";
  BreakIterator bi = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
  bi.setText(s);
  int start = 0;
  int end = 0;
  while ((end = bi.next()) != BreakIterator.DONE) {
    System.out.println(s.substring(start, end));
    start = end;
  }
```